# Use boto to update ElasticBeanstalk environment options

Tags: amazon-web-services, python, elastic-beanstalk, boto

Boto has a function, update_environment, that allows the user to update options in an AWS ElasticBeanstalk environment.

Using the AWS CLI, this would typically be actioned as follows:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --environment-name my-env --option-settings Namespace=aws:autoscaling:asg,OptionName=MinSize,Value=1
```

In Boto, update_environment takes a List parameter for option_settings, as described here:

http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/beanstalk.html

```
update_environment(environment_id=None, environment_name=None, version_label=None, template_name=None, description=None, option_settings=None, options_to_remove=None, tier_name=None, tier_type=None, tier_version='1.0')
```

I've tried various methods of passing the string

```
Namespace=aws:autoscaling:asg,OptionName=MinSize,Value=1
```

as a List, but none seem to work. The API keeps telling me:

```
Invalid option specification
```

Does anyone know what the correct format for the List is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out by looking at the Python source code for boto. Correct format is:

```
option_settings=[("aws:autoscaling:asg","MinSize","1"),("aws:autoscaling:asg","MaxSize","4")]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the code is working for me.

try:
client = boto3.client('elasticbeanstalk', region_name=AWS_REGION)
response = client.update_environment(
EnvironmentName='envname',
OptionSettings=[
{
'Namespace': 'aws:autoscaling:asg:launchconfiguration',
'OptionName': 'MinSize',
'Value': '0'
},
{
'Namespace': 'aws:autoscaling:asg:launchconfiguration',
'OptionName': 'MaxSize',
'Value': '0'
}
],)
except ClientError as err:
print("Failed to update environment.\n" + str(err))
return False
return True